Alert Sys Admin when mass update or delete is performed on any objects
As a Sys Admin, I want to be notified by email when a mass update or deletion occurs in any object by any developer in the org. Is there an out-of-the-box feature that can be enabled in Salesforce or any managed package offer such feature? I know we can build a custom trigger/Flow on an object for such behavior but has to be extended for each key object?
Thanks in Advance.

The answer here might be worth looking at, but you could potentially look at a before delete trigger to achieve this. What would you classify as a 'mass' delete though?

Besides managed package, there is no standard solution but if we go for custom solution then we can leverage CDC functionality as below:

Enable CDC for desired objects: Navigate to Setup > Develop > Change Data Capture. Select the specific Salesforce objects you want to monitor for mass updates.
Create a custom channel: Within the CDC settings, define a custom channel to receive change event notifications.
Develop async Trigger/flow to handle notifications.
Ref: https://www.apexhours.com/change-data-capture-in-salesforce/


But how would CDC determine that the delete was part of a mass action compared to a single action?  Please include more detail about this.
